# select one cell at a time in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When I tap a cell in `UITableView` then the cell is selected and show selection with blue color.

But duration the loading next when a tap to one another cell that is also show as selected with blue.

Can I stop multiple selection in a `UITableView`? or deselect the cells for selection after one cell is selected? and also allow to be selectable when i return to this view.

Comment: could you mind to provide more information or show part of your code to us? It is difficult to debug if there is just some text description.

Answer (score 1):

Best to use:

```
[your_UITableView setAllowsSelection:false];
```

Answer (score 0):

Every tableView has the method *-deselectRowAtIndexPath:*. You can use it whenever the user taps a cell (inside the *-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:*) or any other spot you want to use it.